Imagick throwing on any png file
I'm testing my thumbnaling system with Imagick implementation and formats jpg, webp work fine but with png it always throws:
"improper image header `\/tmp\/magick-fj49nThGt9uvW0CFbLJj7XGsqT7x30OC' @ error\/png.c\/ReadPNGImage\/4107 => \/var\/www\/html\/Dullahan\/thumbnail\/Application\/Generator\/ImagickThumbnailGenerator.php => 89"
[
    {
        "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/Dullahan\/thumbnail\/Application\/Generator\/ImagickThumbnailGenerator.php",
        "line": 89,
        "function": "readImageFile",
        "class": "Imagick",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/Dullahan\/thumbnail\/Application\/Generator\/ImagickThumbnailGenerator.php",
        "line": 54,
        "function": "generateThumbnailFile",
        "class": "Dullahan\\Thumbnail\\Application\\Generator\\ImagickThumbnailGenerator",
        "type": "->"
    },
 [...]

I've tried reinstalling the imagick on the system with imei (https://github.com/SoftCreatR/imei/) but didn't help.
I'm using PHP 8.3 and here is my imagick extension info:
/etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini,
imagick
imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.7.0
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
imagick.allow_zero_dimension_images => 0 => 0
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
imagick.set_single_thread => 1 => 1
imagick.shutdown_sleep_count => 10 => 10
imagick.skip_version_check => 1 => 1

Imagick version:

Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-36 Q16-HDRI x86_64 58ddb87ca:20240726
https://imagemagick.org Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php Features: Cipher
DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(4.5)  Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu
fftw fontconfig freetype gslib gvc heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg jxl lcms lqr
ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raqm raw rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml
zip zlib zstd Compiler: gcc (11.4)

I've tested my files with online checkers and they deemed them appropriate and not corrupted (used https://onlinepngtools.com/verify-if-image-is-png).
I'm loading and resizing file using this code (same code for all extensions):
        $resource = $structure->getResource();
        $imagick = new \Imagick();
        $imagick->readImageFile($resource); // Throw is coming from here

        $imagick->resizeImage(
            $width ?? $imagick->getImageWidth(),
            $height ?? $imagick->getImageHeight(),
            \Imagick::FILTER_CATROM,
            0,
            $config->autoResize,
        );

UPDATE
Additionaly I'm getting sometimes an error on jpg resizing:
"insufficient image data in file `\/tmp\/magick-80xEWLOtzkO2kqgFNI5LGEVZ2iBToQlR' @ error\/jpeg.c\/ReadJPEGImage_\/1166 => \/var\/www\/html\/Dullahan\/thumbnail\/Application\/Generator\/ImagickThumbnailGenerator.php => 89"
[
    {
        "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/Dullahan\/thumbnail\/Application\/Generator\/ImagickThumbnailGenerator.php",
        "line": 89,
        "function": "readImageFile",
        "class": "Imagick",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/Dullahan\/thumbnail\/Application\/Generator\/ImagickThumbnailGenerator.php",
        "line": 54,
        "function": "generateThumbnailFile",
        "class": "Dullahan\\Thumbnail\\Application\\Generator\\ImagickThumbnailGenerator",
        "type": "->"
    },

Also, everything works fine when using cli command magick to resize images.
magick check.png -resize 100x100 new.png

UPDATE 2
Issue is only present when using file handle - loading file to memory and passing as string seems to work fine:
$resource = $structure->getResource();
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->readImageBlob(stream_get_contents($resource));

UPDATE 3
Okay, I've managed to get it working (a little) with this:
$resource = $structure->getResource();
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$file = fopen('/tmp/test', 'w');
stream_copy_to_stream($resource, $file);
fclose($file);
// I have to close a handle and open it again otherwise it doesn't see a thing even with clearstatcache
$file = fopen('/tmp/test', 'r');
$imagick->readImageFile($file);

Can someone explain to me why one file handle is better than the other? And maybe a better way to do this? My main focus is to not load the file into the memory, but to just pass it to the Imagick.

Does readImageFile() throw the exception, or $structure->getResource()?

@ChrisHaas I've updated my question so it would be a little more obvious what is causing the error.

Can you post the version of ImageMagick that you are using, which is different than the imagick extension.

@ChrisHaas I've added imagick version

If you run phpinfo(); does the ImageMagick supported formats line contain PNG?

What kind of resource / class of object is $resource? readImageFile() explicitly expects a file handle, perhaps the IMagick code is trying to do something your provided stream doesn't support, like rewinding.

(Which would also explain why it works fine once you read the whole thing to a string.)

@AlexHowansky it does contain PNG (PNG, PNG00, PNG24, PNG32, PNG48, PNG64, PNG8). The $resource holds a variable of type resource (from gettype) which should be a file handle... I will give it a closer look as this is might be a little different as this is from PHPCR on a Jackrabbit (binary type).

Posting solution with which I'm going for now.
Thanks to @AlexHowansky I've figured that the stream I'm getting is somewhat corrupted (for example stream_get_meta_data returns empty array). Can't really do anything about that.
At some later point I'm creating a temporary file handle in which I will be saving thumbnail, so my solution was to move creation of tmp a little earlier and copy the contents of the file into it then pass tmp to Imagick:
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$tmp = tmpfile();
stream_copy_to_stream($resource, $tmp);
rewind($tmp);
$imagick->readImageFile($tmp);
$imagick->resizeImage(
    $width ?? $imagick->getImageWidth(),
    $height ?? $imagick->getImageHeight(),
    \Imagick::FILTER_CATROM,
    0,
    $config->autoResize,
);
$imagick->writeImageFile($tmp);
$imagick->destroy();

With this, I can be sure that passed handle is not corrupted (I left out data validation like: tmpfile() didn't return false).
